# Encapsulate function using C11 preprocessor

Tags: c, insert, c-preprocessor

I am currently working on a project in C in which there are various function that all need become encapsulated in between two other functions. Schematically, it looks like this:

```
int func1(int arg) {
  prepare();
  doStuff();
  undo();
  return stuff;
}
char func2(int arg1, char* arg2) {
  prepare();
  doOtherStuff();
  undo();
  return results;
}
```

I've heard the preprocessor is quite powerful, so is it possible to insert the `prepare()` and `undo()` functions before and after the actual function body using some preprocessor mumbo-jumbo? I know that it is highly advised not to use the preprocessor if it can be avoided, yet I still am curious whether it is possible.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
#define MY_MACRO(doStuff) \
{                         \
    prepare();            \
    doStuff               \
    undo();               \
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna delete this answer as soon as you read it, because I don't consider it highly voluable.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go ahead and remove the post altogether then.

Comment: Did you make sure that it works for you? The `doStuff` argument is not a function name of course, but any piece of code that you want to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, an alternative would be to set up some form of function pointer template system:

```
typedef void stuff_t (void*);

void execute (stuff_t* stuff, void* result)
{
  prepare();  
  stuff(result);
  undo();
}

int func1(int arg) {
  int result;
  execute(do_stuff, &result);
  return result;
}

char func2(int arg1, char* arg2) {
  char result;
  execute(doOtherStuff, &result);
  return result;
}
```

Whether this is a good idea or not depends on what the code is actually supposed to do and what requirements there are on code re-usability.

Comment: Somebody has down-voted my answer without a comment. Can you see anything wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos I suppose it depends on what "doStuff" is. It has to be something that can get evaluated to a pre-processor token. And possibly a missing semi-colon? `MY_MACRO(a=b);` won't compile, but `MY_MACRO(a=b;);` will.

Comment: Well, the `doStuff` argument is any piece of code that you want to be executed (this is also mentioned in a comment to the OP). For example `a=b; c=d;`. So you are not restricted to a single statement. Of course, I could have added that semi-colon just in case, but I felt that it would be missing the point here, because "any piece of code" obviously means "any **legal** piece of code". So I don't see why this could be a good excuse for down-vote.